# Transpose table then set and rename index

Tags: pandas

I want to transpose a table and rename the index.

If I display the `df` with *existing* index `Time` I get

```
Time  v1   v2
1     0.5  0.3
2     0.2  0.1
3     0.3  0.3
```

and after `df.transpose()` I'm at

```
Time  1    2    3
v1    0.5  0.2  0.3
v2    0.3  0.1  0.3
```

Interestingly if I do now `df.Time` I get

> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'`

although it gets displayed in the output.

I can't find a way to easily rename the column `Time` to `Variable` and set that as the new index ..

I tried `df.reset_index().set_index("index")` but what I get is something that looks like this:

```
Time   1    2    3
index
v1     0.5  0.2  0.3
v2     0.3  0.1  0.3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need only rename column names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename):

```
print (df.transpose().rename_axis('Variable', axis=1))
Variable    1    2    3
v1        0.5  0.2  0.3
v2        0.3  0.1  0.3
```

Or set new column names by assign name:

```
df1 = df.transpose()
df1.columns.name = 'Var'
print (df1)
Var    1    2    3
v1   0.5  0.2  0.3
v2   0.3  0.1  0.3
```

But I think you need set new column from `index` and then rename column `index` to `var`, also reset column names to `None`:

```
df1 = df.transpose().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'var'})
df1.columns.name = None
print (df1)
  var    1    2    3
0  v1  0.5  0.2  0.3
1  v2  0.3  0.1  0.3
```

Comment: You're right - I need to have the `var` column set as index but the last one does not remove the `Time` column