# How can I pivot dataframe in a specific way in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small question about pandas dataframe.
How can I pivot my dataframe from this

```
AGE       | GROUP-A | ... | GROUP-Q 
----------|---------|-----|---------
00-04     |77       |     |133
05-17     |117      |     |106
18-25     |64       |     |110
```

to this

```
GROUP | 00-04 | 05-17 | 18-25 
------|-------|-------|-------
A     |77     |117    |64
...   |       |       | 
Q     |133    |106    |110
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get - is it a single line including both column names and values that you want to convert to a table with column names int the first row, and values in the following rows?

Comment: Sorry I don't know why i can't put it in a tabular form. I'm trying to resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you post say 3 rows of your original text, and 3 rows of how you would like the output to look like? That may help understanding better what you need?

Comment: is it better ike this ?

Comment: I don't think you are after a `pivot table`. I think what you really want to do is `df.transpose()`. You will need to then do some more work to change the column/row names as you have them in the question. The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874956/transpose-table-then-set-and-rename-index) may help you with that.

Comment: Thanks, after rewriting the question, I agree it’s a traspose. I am very sorry you got downvoted by some angry passerby-this should stop happening on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by setting 'AGE' as your index, followed by [`pd.DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AGE': ['00-04', '05-17', '18-25'],
                   'GROUP-A': [77, 117, 64],
                   'GROUP-Q': [133, 106, 110]})

res = df.set_index('AGE')\
        .transpose()

print(res)

AGE      00-04  05-17  18-25
GROUP-A     77    117     64
GROUP-Q    133    106    110
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @JPP setup, you can use the following to get your exact expected output in your question.

```
df.set_index('AGE').rename(columns=lambda x: x[-1])\
  .T.rename_axis('GROUP').rename_axis([None], axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  GROUP  00-04  05-17  18-25
0     A     77    117     64
1     Q    133    106    110
```

*Note:* `.T` is the same as `.transpose`, just easier to type.